# the relation between old matrix of $\alpha$ with respect to standard basis and new matrix of $\alpha$ with respect to new basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The question is given below:

> [image]

But in order to answer it I need to understand the answer of this question:

What is the relation between old matrix of $\alpha$ with respect to standard basis and new matrix of alpha with respect to new basis? could anyone explain the answer of this question for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asserting that the first column of the new matrix consists only of zeros is equivalent to$$\alpha.\begin{bmatrix}a\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.\tag1$$But$$\alpha.\begin{bmatrix}a\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2a-2\\a-1\\a-1\end{bmatrix}.\tag2$$The only way of having both $(1)$ and $(2)$ is to have $a=1$. And it turns out that$$\alpha.\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }\alpha.\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=4\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$and therefore, yes, if $a=1$, then the representation of $\alpha$ with respect to the new basis is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: How do you get (2)? And do you have any answer for my question I posed above ?

Comment: Here is my question " What is the relation between old matrix of $\alpha$ with respect to standard basis and new matrix of alpha with respect to new basis?"

Comment: I got $(2)$ just by computing $\alpha.\begin{bmatrix}a\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. And the relation is this: if $\beta$ is the new matrix, then$$\beta=\begin{bmatrix}a&-2&1\\-1&a&1\\0&1&a\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.\alpha.\begin{bmatrix}a&-2&1\\-1&a&1\\0&1&a\end{bmatrix}.$$